# C# Parse text qualified file into separate strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse and split the following sample text file using dotnet c# in order to break each single data points into separate strings.

> ```
> §Id§|§Name§|§UpdateDate§|§Description§
> 1|§AAA/FE-45§|2000-02-02 00:00:00|§§
> 2|§BBB-123§|2000-02-03 00:00:00|§§
> 3|§CC|45§|2000-02-07 00:00:00|§The following,
> is a multiline description
> please check Name:
> CC|45 as soon as possible§
> ```

File Properties:

> ```
> CodePage: ANSI
> Column Headers: Yes
> Row Delimiter: {CR}{LF}
> Column Delimiter: | (Vertical Bar)
> Text Qualifier: §
> ```

The trouble I have is that the text type columns are qualified with a non standard symbol and the given text could be a block of multi-line text that may contain various symbols such as {CRLF}, {LF} or even | (Vertical Bar).

From what I can read around, i cannot use TextFieldParser because it only handles double quote qualifier and Bulk Insert does not support text qualifier.
I'm no c# expert at all; I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel and ideally would like to use the best practices. But I also like to understand and "own" what I produce so I would prefer to avoid Libraries such as Filehelpers.
Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: Did you check the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method ?

Comment: The problem is that the vertical bar can be not only a column delimiter but a part of a column value.

Comment: Why not just change the funky text delimeters to " marks then? that would still leave you valid data

Comment: I would change the column delimiter to something else, e.g. `TAB` character.

Comment: Just as a reminder, `String.Split` supports regexps if the splitting needs something more..... detailed than a simple char/char array

Comment: @BugFinder Might be because the OP has no control over the file generation ?

Comment: No, I meant after reading in the file.

Comment: @BugFinder you still have to find the delimiter with program logic in that case...

Comment: @BugFinder you mean swap § symbol with " in order to use TextFieldParser class ? Why not, indeed. I can and will try that and report back.

Comment: @Gabor I could but the TAB character is also sometimes present in the description field value.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I looked into the String.Split() method but I failed to split each datarow new line as CRLF delimiter was contained in the "Description" field as well. Do you have a sample code I could look into ?

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach would be to use finite automata for this. In your case, you can try the following code:

```
    public static List<string[]> split(string s)
    {
        bool ins = false;
        int no = 3;
        var L = new List<string>();
        var Res = new List<string[]>();
        var B = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '§':
                    if (ins)
                    {
                        ins = false;
                        L.Add(B.ToString());
                        if (no == 0)
                        {
                            Res.Add(L.ToArray<string>());
                            L.Clear();
                            no = 3;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ins = true;
                        B.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                case '|':
                    if (!ins) { no--; }
                    else B.Append(c);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (ins) B.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string pattern = @"(?<id>\d+) \| (?<name>§.+?§) \| (?<date>\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \s \d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \| (?<desc>§.*?§)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline);

string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
text = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

var matches = regex.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["id"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["name"].Value.Trim('§'));
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["date"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["desc"].Value.Trim('§'));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```